# Jupyter is not using my virtual environment in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm currently having problems getting Jupyter to connect to my kernel that I made using my virtualenv.

Here's what I did:

I first created my virtual environment by doing:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Then I activated the venv in my terminal, and installed the packages that I needed for my project:

```
pip install numpy pandas matplotlib ipykernel jupyter jupyterlab
```

Then I created a kernel from my venv so that Jupyter can use by doing:

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=python_data_analytics
```

Afterwards, I tried to get VSCode to use my venv and I got it to use the interpreter at `bin/ipython3` of my venv. As for Jupyter, I got it to use the kernel I made from a dropdown menu.

Then when I tried to execute the first cell of my notebook to import my libraries, Python says that it can't find my libraries.

Here's a screenshot of the end result:

[image: VSCode screenshot of the end result]

It seems that Jupyter is not using the virtual environment that I made and it's falling back to the system's interpreter. I'm not sure how should I go about fixing this problem. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Lower left corner and upper right corner should both point to your venv. They are different in your screenshot

Comment: On the bottom left corner, I have it set to be the interpreter at `./python_data_analytics/venv/bin/ipython3` and the one on the top right corner is set to be kernel that points to `./python_data_analytics/venv/bin/python3`. I did try to change the interpreter to just be python3, but the issue is that it's an alias to the system's interpreter. I'm not able to grab the environment.

Comment: If you open a Python instance in the terminal in VSC, can you confirm the venv is activated and has your packages installed? I believe this would confirm the issue is with the kernel.

Comment: I opened up a Python instance, and I tried to import Pandas, but it wasn't able to. I then decided to have VSCode open up the `python_data_analytics` folder directly, and the editor prompted me if I wanted to use the venv. I confirmed that I want to use it, and now everytime I open up the terminal, it would activate my venv.

Comment: Oh wow! I refreshed VSCode, and my issue just went away. I'm able to import my libraries now! Thanks! :D

Comment: Awesome! Not sure I can take credit for "randomly pushing buttons" but I'm glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but in the left bottom option, where there is a label called "Python 3.9.5..." you can select your desired environment.